# Replacing a string completely with a new string or word in python

Tags: python, string, text

I have a data frame which has two columns, "Title" and "Description". The title column has a bunch of titles related to clinical lab tests. Unfortunately, most of the titles are repeat of same test but  due to minor changes in the titles,  titles are shown as  unique.

```
values = [('Complete blood picture', 'AB'), ('Complete BLOOD test', 'AB'), ('blood glucose', 'AB'), ('COMplete blood Profile', 'AB')]
labels = ['title', 'description']
import pandas as pd
labtest = pd.DataFrame.from_records(values, columns = labels) # Create data frame
labtest = labtest.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())  # Convert columns to string and lower case
labtest['title'].str.contains("blood")  # Search for blood
```

Before:

```
Title                       Description
Complete blood test         AB
COMPLETE Blood test\        AB
Blood glucose               AB
Complete blood picture      AB
```

After: [This is how i would like the data frame to look like]

```
Title                       Description
Blood test                   AB
Blood test                   AB
Blood test                   AB
Blood test                   AB
```

I would like to search for the word "blood" in each title and if its true, then change the whole title with "Blood test".

P.S I am new to python and working with text data, i have only managed to come as far as search for the word "blood".

Comment: @furas, typo -> str.replace()

Comment: In your example, is "average blood glucose (abg)" always the entire string?  Or could there be other text at the beginning or end that you want to keep?

Comment: did you try to use `str.replace()`? if not then try it first.

Comment: @VISWESWARANNAGASIVAM thank you. It was too late to edit comment so I wrote new one.

Comment: You the better use panda to do this

Comment: @JohnGordon I want to find the number of times "average blood glucose (abg)" appears in the title column and replace with "Blood Test". There are other titles (which are not shown in the above screen shot) which i want to change as  "Blood Test".

Comment: Post some data in text format and expected output , if you are not putting the effort in code at least put in question, You can also use counter or defaultdict.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul I have edited the question. I apologize for not being clear. Going forward, i will make sure it doesn't happen.

Comment: @KarthikShanmukha don't use [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul Thanks for sharing the link. I have re-edited the question.

Comment: @KarthikShanmukha have you checked the solution?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul Thank you so much  for the answer. I am new to python and programming in general. I am familiar with R and i am trying to make a switch to python. I am trying to understand the solution which you have suggested. Since i am not familiar with this, i am  having a little hard time to figure things out. I will let you know if this works out.

Comment: @KarthikShanmukha if it helps you can accept the answer, or if you have any confusion you can move this discussion to chat.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul I wish i was more clear the first time i asked the question. I edited the question again, attached a reproducible example. I would really appreciate if you could help me figure this out. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an exact solution because i don't know format of your data  , I am just giving you an example with txt file , You can take help from this code :

If file.txt contains :

```
Title                       Description
Complete blood test         ABO group
COMPLETE Blood test\        ABO group
Blood glucose               ABO group
Complete blood picture      ABO group
```

Code:

```
track_dublicate={}
with open('file.txt') as f:

    for line_no,line in enumerate(f):
        if line_no==0:
            pass
        else:
            if tuple(line.split()[-2:]) not in track_dublicate:
                track_dublicate[tuple(line.split()[-2:])]=line.split()[:-2]
            else:
                track_dublicate[tuple(line.split()[-2:])]='Blood test'

print(track_dublicate)
#you can save this data to a new file where you want.
```

output:

```
{('ABO', 'group'): 'Blood test'}
```